# Difference between initializing variables in def and doing so in normal method

Tags: ruby, initialization, instance-variables

Suppose I have two classes like:

```
class Abc
  def initialize(arg1, arg2)
    @a = arg1
    @b = arg2
  end

  def sum
    return @a+@b
  end
end

obj = Abc.new(2, 3)
obj.add # => 5
```

or

```
class Abc1
  def sum(arg1, arg2)
    return arg1+arg2
  end
end

obj = Abc1.new
obj.sum(2,3) # =>5
```

In both classes, I call a `sum` method and get `5` as the result. Which approach is better and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the use case. If the variables are to be shared among other method calls on the object, then it makes sense to initialize them as instance variables. If they are only used for a particular method call, then they should be passed as method arguments.

So both can be potentially correct, but in your particular code, the second one (`Abc1`) does not make (much) sense since in the method call of `sum`, nothing particular to an `Abc1` instance is used in the execution. It would make sense as a class method:

```
class Abc1
  def self.sum(arg1, arg2)
    arg1 + arg2
  end
end

Abc1.sum(2,3) # =>5
```